# Java Script functions (Click) not calling when using WkWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

All,

I am displaying a URL in UIWebview and i have to perform some click actions and I am able to using click function in javascript (I am able to get callbacks to objective C code as well).

Now i want to migrate to WKWebview and i have below code written with delegate methods

```
    WKPreferences *preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = YES;


    WKWebViewConfiguration* configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    configuration.preferences = preferences;
    self.webKitView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: [[self view] bounds]configuration:configuration];
    self.webKitView.navigationDelegate = self;

    [self.webKitView loadHTMLString:htmlString1 baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.webKitView];
```

Delegate method

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler{

  NSURLRequest *request = navigationAction.request;

  decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);

}

Now i am able to display same as in Webview, I am performing **Click** actions but i am not able to call.

Can any one how can i proceed